# configuring theano in windows ? ' where to put the .theanorc.txt

Tags: python, theano, deep-learning, keras

I've followed this installation tutorial : 
http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install_windows.html#install-windows

As described in the tutorial, I've put the `.theanorc.txt` file in :

```
c:\scisoft\WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.4\settings
```

I was able to run the test program from the shell created by `env.bat` and to see the it uses the GPU.

Now I want to develop from pycharm not the "cmd", but there is get:

```
WARNING (theano.configdefaults): g++ not detected ! 
Theano will be unable to execute optimized C-implementations 
(for both CPU and GPU) and will default to Python implementations. 
Performance will be severely degraded. 
To remove this warning, set Theano flags cxx to an empty string.
```

I assume because he can't find the .theanorc.txt

So I found this tutorial: 
http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/config.html

He says to put the file in `$HOME`, but i don't have such environment variable.
I've tried to add it, but it didn't helped.

Any ideas ? I red tens of questions regarding it in stack overflow, but couldn't find an answer to this

Answer (score 1):

I did this myself just recently... nearly the exact situation!

If you running an external IDE (i.e., not WinPython/Spyder), you need to put .theanorc in your Windows Users folder.

For example: C:\Users[Your Name]\

Note, I also recommend using the filename .theanorc not .theanorc.txt. I read that either works, but I seem to recall only one of them working for me.